# Why do Cookies get their own property on HttpRequest?

Tags: asp.net-core

Why are Cookies more important than other HTTP headers?  If I iterate through the header dictionary, do I see the cookies again, or have they been removed?

Comment: Would you please let me know how to create and read cookies in vNext web applications

Answer (score 0):

We haven't gone through and made all of the appropriate headers first class as yet (they all won't be but some will). Everything that's first class was made that way because they were being used. We added Cookies because of the CookieMiddleware.

Comment: Do we really want to keep increasing the surface area of the abstract HttpRequest each time a blessed piece of middleware needs to access a header?  Don't all headers get used by someone? It would be nice if there wasn't a first class and second class way of accessing headers.  Would it be possible to access these headers via a Feature?